# "Deprecating the Observer Pattern" -- code examples in some other language?

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

I'm trying to understand the paper [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/148043/files/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) which seems to be somewhat influential in the development of "Reactive" programming.

However, all the examples are in Scala which is hindering my understanding.
Has anyone translated these examples into a more commonly known language like Java or JavaScript?  Or is there a comparable introduction with examples in a language used by more than like 7 people? :)

If this belongs in a different stackwhatever, please let me know.

Comment: There are dozens of us. Dozens!

Comment: Still reading the paper, but I would say that doing the same in Java would be really cumbersome. May be possible in JavaScript, but without the same type safety...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article argues that the observer pattern causes many bugs because it is hard to reason about(needs to use side-effects to maintain state, lack of uniformity, inversion of control, ...) and it is difficult to apply good practices(separation of concerns, encapsulation, ...) to it.

It then goes on to show how, using Scala.React library, you can transition from an observable-based code base to a reactive one.

In this answer I will use "scalenglish" and "javenglish" to try to explain the code as I understand it.

The first step(Item 2) was to create the Event abstraction. With Event, you now have an uniform interface that can be used to encapsulate observables. Then it goes on and define the "merge" method, which allows then to compose different events.

The second step(Item 3) was to solve the inversion of control problem. To do that, using Scala.React library, they define an DSL where it is possible to translate this:

```
var state = null
observe(event1).then{
    state = new StartState()
    remove_observer(event1)
    observe(event2).then {
        state = new AccumulateState(old_state+new_data)
    }
    observe(event3).then {
        do_something()
        state = null
        remove_observer(event2)
        remove_observer(event3)
    }
}
```

into:

```
once {
   state = new StartState(when(event1))
   until(event3) {
      state = new AccumulateState(when(event2))
   }
   do_something()
}
```

The library transparently defines functions that will wait for the expected events but will NOT stop the execution of your program. In the code above, the methods "once" and "when" and "until" take care of waiting for the event and continuing the execution of the code when expected. You can see also that, in the second snippet, you don't need to associate/remove observers.

The third step(Item 4) was then to create an Signal. Signal is a time-varying value that you can use to define how to evaluate the value of the signal at the moment( the "now" method) and to observe the signal changes(the "changes" method) by returning an Event associated with the Signal. (As a side note, trait in scala is the same as interface in java, but with the added possibility of implementing some of the needed behavior in the trait itself.)

The fourth step(Item 5) is then to integrate Signal and Event into the Scala.Reactor. It makes the Signal and Event traits extend the Reactive trait, and explains how (in scala) is possible to define methods that convert events and signals into dataflows *implicitly*(user-defined implicit conversions is something I tried to find on other languages but it seems to be an scala-only feature).

It then defines combinators(uniform methods that operate over any dataflow)  and explain the problems found while doing so.

The item 6 then goes on to explain how it all was implemented in scala.

The item 7 lists related works on other languages/libraries(including Java)

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)? Description:

> Reactive Extensions for the JVM – a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences for the Java VM.

[This page](http://instil.co/2014/08/05/rxjava-in-different-flavours-of-java/) explains reactive programming using Java 7 en 8 (example shown in 7). For example:

```
Integer[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Observable numberObservable = Observable.from(numbers);

numberObservable.subscribe(
        new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer incomingNumber) {
                System.out.println(incomingNumber);
            }
        },
        new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable error) {
                System.out.println("Error in synchronous observable");
            }
        },
        new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                System.out.println("This observable is finished");
            }

        }
);
```

Comment: I don't know if it fits. The article is about abstracting away the observer pattern, as it argues this pattern is the main cause of bugs in some softwares

Comment: Indeed, and RxJava seems to be the Java incarnation of the ideas from that paper, so at least you can see how a reactive version of a program would look like and compare this with an observer pattern based version (that you may have to create yourself).

Comment: @Governa Yes, that seems to be the premise of the paper, the Observer pattern causes too many bugs, "their" approach, which has come to be called "Reactive" is, of course, the savior of those worshiping the false deity Observable (or something like that).   The RxJava page has me confused though because its all about an Observable.

Comment: @JohnHascall I think you're right, it *is* a bit confusing, it would have been more clear had they called it 'Observer Pattern 2.0' or something..